# How do I complete the Meditation achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The class-specific Monk achievement Meditation says that I need to "Use Mantra skills to grant a beneficial effect to an ally 200 times."

I use mantras constantly and renew them as soon as they wear off, but I never get any progress towards this achievement. I've tried every mantra I have. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Do followers and other following NPCs not count as allies? Are my Mantra skills granting no beneficial effect to my allies? Is there a specific mantra(s) that I need to be using to get progress on this one? Is this multiplayer-only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "ally" it means another player, not NPCs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If that's true, then I think it's a stupid achievement. It's the only class achievement that *requires* you to play multiplayer co-op and the description does not make that clear.

Comment: Confirmed, it works only with human allies in co-op.

Answer (score -1):

It's fairly specific, as it says ally, not follower.